# updateAll with relationships in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I try update all Orders in the system, but have a "where" condition.
How can I do that in CakePHP 2.3?

```
// OrderFood.php (Model)
$orderFood = $this->updateAll(
    array(
        'OrderFood.price' => 'OrderFood.original_price',
        'OrderFood.discount_percent' => 0,
        'OrderFood.discount_amount' => 0,
    ),
    array(
        'Order.check_num' => $check_num
    )
);
```

---

```
// OrderFood.php (Model)
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Order' => array(
        'className' => 'Order',
        'foreignKey' => 'order_num',
    ),
    'Food' => array(
        'className' => 'Food',
        'foreignKey' => 'food_num'
    )
);
```

---

```
// Order.php (Model)
/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $hasMany = array(
    'OrderDrink' => array(
        'className' => 'OrderDrink',
        'foreignKey' => 'order_num'
    ),
    'OrderFood' => array(
        'className' => 'OrderFood',
        'foreignKey' => 'order_num'
    )
);
```

When I try do that, Cake return this error message:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERRO: faltando entrada para tabela "Order" na cláusula FROM LINE 1: ...ROM "public"."order_foods" AS "OrderFood" WHERE "Order"."c... ^

SQL Query: SELECT "OrderFood"."order_num" AS "OrderFood__order_num" FROM "public"."order_foods" AS "OrderFood" WHERE "Order"."check_num" = 358171

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp
```

Comment: Aren't you confusing saveAll() and updateAll() here?

Comment: Yep, sorry. I was testing saveAll, and not work too.

Comment: what is there to test? please read the documentation on how to use those two methods - and when to use which. So you did actually use updateAll() but you accidently wrote saveAll() in your question?

Comment: No my friend. I'm using updateAll, but doesn't work, so I test saveAll... When I was writing this question I do 'ctrl+z', and forget the saveAll, just this. And, I read documentation, and not understand... because that, I'm here in Stack.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update your `OrderFood` model but you are passing in a condition for the `Order` model.  If you look at the SQL error your WHERE clause is referencing the `Order` table which was not been included in the statement.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but one simple solution would be to query the Order table first and get the `order_num` for your `check_num`.  Then change the condition in `updateAll()` to `OrderFood.order_num' => $order_num`.